# A Topological Source with an Index Family set to $\emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology

Given a Source like this:

$(f_i: \underline{X}  \rightarrow \underline{Y}_i)_{i \in I}$, where $I$ is an index-family.

What happens if $I = \emptyset$?

In H. Herrlich's Book "Topologie 1" he claims the Source is equal to $\underline X$.

How can one prove that fact? To me if $I = \emptyset$, then this sequence of functions is not well-defined.

Comment: I have never seen the word "source" being used in this context. Is there another name for what you are talking about?

Comment: Please write down the precise definition of a "source" in your question to make it self-contained for people without access to the book.

Comment: I'm not sure what "source" means here, but I suspect this is the limit of these maps, i.e. a map $\underline X\to Y$ and maps $Y\to \underline Y_i$ with respect to which this is universal. If $I$ is empty, then universality just means that this is the universal map from $\underline X$, which is the identity.

Comment: In German It's called _Quelle_. I think the translation is a _Source_. The definition you can see on the second line. Basically an ordered set of maps, which all go from a topological space $\underline X$ into respective topological space $\underline Y_i$.

Comment: @СССР Sure, but you say "he claims the Source" of $(f_i:\underline{X}\to \underline{Y}_i)_{i\in I}$ is $\underline{X}$. What is "the Source" of a collection of maps $(f_i:\underline{X}\to \underline{Y}_i)_{i\in I}$. Is it the (categorical) limit like tomasz suggested?

Comment: I guess he calls the collection of this form itself a _Source_. He calls such a collection an _initial source_ if in $\underline X = (X, T)$.  _T_ - is the smallest topology, that makes each $f_i$ continuous.

Comment: @СССР I see. So what you are looking it is the initial topology corresponding to these functions (https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology). In that case, the initial topology on $\underline{X}$ when $I=\emptyset$ is the indiscrete topology since that is the smallest topology for which an empty collection of functions are continuous.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it! What I don't get is how an **empty** collection of functions can be continuous? In fact, functions and not a collection are supposed to be continuous or not and in our case they just don't exist. E.g. it's like stating that some non-existing number is even (or odd, or prime, etc.)

Comment: @СССР Yes, this sort of "empty" situation comes up in math frequently. If I give you an empty collection of functions, then it is vacuously true that those functions are continuous. It is perfectly well-defined, although slightly unintuitive at first. More generally, for any predicate $P$, it is vacuously true that $(\forall x\in\emptyset)P(x)$. Check out https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth for more technical information.

Comment: I get it now. It's because from _false_ follows anything... Can you paste your comment with the initial topology plus your last comment and I'd be glad to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 81 of said book he states indeed that for $I=\emptyset$, the *source* (a fancy name for a set of functions with a common domain) $(f_i: X \to Y_i)_{i \in I}$ is an initial source iff $X$ is indiscrete. This holds because if we universally quantify over an empty domain the resulting statement is *true*, e.g. because there can be no counterexample to $\forall x \in \emptyset: P(x)$ in any empty domain. See [wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) for some more info.

So for *any* topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ we have that

$$\forall i \in I: f_i: (X,\mathcal{T}) \to Y_i \text{ is continuous }$$

holds when $I=\emptyset$, so the *minimal* such topology is the minimal topology überhaupt, i.e. the indiscrete one, so that satisfies the definitional property for being an initial source. Note that this is nicely dual to the final sink with common codomain $X$ and $I=\emptyset$ being the discrete topology on $X$.

Comment: I assume analogously, for the set of functions with a common **target** domain (i.e. a _Sink_). The  _Final Topology_  would then be the _Descrete Topology_, as it is the biggest one that makes non-existent family of functions continuous.

Comment: @СССР yes, that’s explicitly mentioned in the book as well, as I did too.